# Who will do it: "your team or us" vs "your team or we"

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-choice

Just would like to know which is correct?

> 1. Who will do it, your team or us?
> 2. Who will do it, your team or we?

Any other way to ask the question above more efficiently (and professionally)?

Comment: Personally, I'd go for "Who will do it, your team or ours?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*We* is the correct subject pronoun, but if the subject is not expressed right before the verb for some reason, it generally sounds better if the object pronoun is used, especially if at the end of the sentence.  There's probably a rule or theory explaining why but it's most likely just because if you end a sentence with a subject pronoun, a listener may think the sentence is incomplete if he/she wasn't paying 100% attention.

> Who will do it, your team or us?

I think only the most pedantic would wonder why you didn't reword the sentence to use *we* instead of *us*.  You would not have to worry about it sounding unprofessional to anyone except an English major.

You can try:

> Should we do it, or should your team do it?

While this is wordier, it is clearer and avoids the issue entirely.